# Android game-development

Tags: java, android, frameworks

After having created a bunch of utility apps and having familiarity with Java, I am curious about going into simple game development. I found out the there are game development frameworks available but I was wondering if that is the "correct" method of doing it even though Java is easy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like `Java`, you'll like `C#`, as it is very similar to `Java/C++`. As such, you should probably look into `Unity 3D`. It's a pretty good game engine with which you can use `C#`, `Javascript`, or `Boo` to create nice little 2D or 3D games. It is multiplatform, so you can create games for `Android`, `iOS`, `Windows Phone`, or a bunch of other things.